# Parametric Equation to find the Stationary Point

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis

[The Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lumlh.png)

In University we learn the Parametric Equation. And in order to find the Stationary Point we use this formula. Could you please give a proof of it, and explain how these formula always works

Comment: If this is comping from a university course, don’t you have an instructor or teaching assistant that you can ask for clarification? Or is this a homework assignment for that course?

Comment: Actually, because of the COVID-19 they gave us the presentation and the exercises with the corrections. They explain the corrections, but we dont learn any proof. I dont want to learn the formula by heart, but understand it